# How to perform expansion in .apk files?

Tags: android, google-play, google-play-services, apk, android-applicationinfo

I am developing an Android application. I created my .obb file in the external storage and I can access it.  I want to test the expansion process in my app before my welcome screen navigates to main screen if the file exists or not, before uploading it to the play store. Links I have referred : How can I achieve it? [Android Developers](http://developer.android.com/google/play/expansion-files.html),[Example Link](http://sapandiwakar.in/how-to-set-up-android-app-to-support-expansion-files/)